# How to get rid of vertical and horizontal scroll bar using html,css and bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have used html,css and bootstrap to design this section but the problem is whichever video I upload has some extra width and height resulting in vertical and horizontal scroll bar. It effects my nav-bar. Any help please? I am mentioning the code and CSS.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Lemonada', cursive;
}

h1,
h2 {
  color: yellow;
}

.home-data-container {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 850px;
  left: 40px;
}

.heading-btn {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.heading-btn:hover {
  color: black;
  background: whitesmoke;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .home-data-container {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Special</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dishes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> DANY</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Hedaer End -->

<!-- Home section -->
<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop muted>
      <source
        src="videos/Seasoning Pizza at Italian Restaurant.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
      />
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="home-data-container">
    <h1 class="home-heading">Food that you cant resist</h1>
    <h2 class="home-heading">Enjoy the marvelous taste</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg heading-btn">
      Get Started
    </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCoX5.jpg)

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I checked adding width and height attributes to the video tag but it didn't work

Comment: Doesn’t look like you tried to format the video element _at all_ so far? So I’m guessing it probably gets its size, from the actual dimensions of the video file. So _specify_ a `max-width` then …?

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. I set the max-width and max-height property and the overflow-x to the hidden. It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add css to video tag and set width:100% ?

Comment: thank you so much. It worked. I set the max-width and max-height property and the overflow-x to the hidden. It worked :)

Comment: you may approve my answer then :)